# Get a numeric value or string from an address of an attached process

Tags: c#, memory, interop, shared-memory

I am building a small tool which allows me to edit in real time the memory of an attached process.

so the tool has 1 numericUpDown and 2 buttons, a get and a set.

my set code is as followed

```
private void sendButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    byte[] stat = BitConverter.GetBytes(Convert.ToInt32(statNumericUpDown.Value.ToString()));
    SetMemory(0x0175914a, stat);
}
```

where I am stuck is reversing that process so I can get numbers from my attached process and send them to my numericUpDown.

I hope I explained well enough and any help would be much appreciated.

**EDIT: Better Explanation**

What I am trying to do is real time edit memory in order to set and get values from my attached process' memory. So lets say in that process there is a value we'll call it Wins. I know the memory address of Wins is 00000001. in my attached process I have say 32 Wins

Now manually I would use a debbuger point to 00000001 copy the bytes at that address, go to a hex to decimal converter, paste those copied bytes (20) and get a return value of 32

what I am trying to achieve is at the press of a button this is all done by system and have the returned value show in my numericUpDown Control

Comment: I'm not quite sure what you are looking to accomplish here but for reading and writing unmanaged memory directly I would recommend using interop services (Marshal class provides excellent utilities). For more information see: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.interopservices.marshal(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: I know how to read and write memory to my attached process that's taken care of with an extension. myextension.setMemory(address, byte) & myextension.GetMemory(address, byte) accomplishes this for me. What am wanting is a way to convert the bytes at a specified address to a numerical value and then have that number show in my numericUpDown control

Answer (score 0):

Surely the reverse of the process would simply be the reverse of what you have, i.e.:

```
byte[] statBytes = GetMemory(0x0175914a);
int stat = BitConverter.ToInt32(statBytes);
statNumericUpDown.Value = stat;
```

The key is [`BitConverter.ToInt32`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.bitconverter.toint32%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) for converting from a byte[] to an `Int32`.